# Calculate normality of each group in a dataset using R

Tags: r, group-by, statistics, data-analysis, bigdata

I have a dataset of about 7 lacs of entries. Suppose it has 5 columns :

```
Cust_Id(around 340 unique Ids), Expense_Type, Expense($), Income_Type and Income($).
```

I want to examine the relative stability of Income and Expense within any `Cust_Id` group as determined by statistical analysis.

I found out the statistical information (mean, median, standard deviation) of the data using the `summaryBy` function of R.

Now I want to find the normality for each group of `Cust_Id`. I used `shapiro.test()` function but it results in a normality score of the whole data and not of the grouped values. Am I in the right path for solving the requirement? I am a newbie in this field. Please suggest ways to solve this.

Sample Data:

```
Cust_Id  Income_Type  Income  Expense_Type  Expense
10001    ABC          4356.89  XYZ          569.45
10003    DEF          5678.34  PQR          4532.43
10006    FRG          5783.43  JHK          9724.56
10001    DEG          5345.34  HTY          7856.34
10008    HGT          678.67   KIL          7893.13
10003    GRT          678.67   JHK          6544.11
```

Comment: Is there a particular value from the test you are looking for?

Comment: Have you tried any of mine? The final one using split is quite simple. Call your sample data data and change Expenses($) to Income for the income normality of each id group like you were trying to do with Cedric's answer.

Comment: Sorry I thought that your data frame was named Cust_id, I have changed my script.

Comment: @Pierre I want to find the normality score of Income and Expense for each Customer Id group.

Comment: Hey I got the result from both the approaches . Minor tweaks with your code and finally done. Thank you all !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to subset your data, you can use a loop and store the results in a list.

```
listids <- list()
for (ids in unique(df$Cust_Ids)){
    subdf <- subset(x=df, subset=Cust_Ids==ids)
    # apply the rest of your analysis there using subdf, for instance 
    listids[[ids]] <- shapiro.test(subdf$Expense)
}
```

Comment: Just like Oli said you can also use apply, which would be faster

Comment: When helping new users, it is important to get simple things like the names of data frames exactly as they have it. You know to change the names to match, but they don't. You have named the object `Cust_Id` with the column `Ids` and they have an object named `df` with the column `Cust_Id`.

Comment: I understand that the OP did not supply a data frame name in the question, but even with that, calling the object `Cust_Id` will certainly lead to mistakes.

Comment: You are right, I didn't read it right. I will do the change accordingly.

Comment: @Cedric This code is again returning an empty dataframe subdf.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question. Example data would help. If you are looking to test the normality of each column, you can just run the test on each relevant column.

For example if your data set is called `data` and is a data.table see `class(data)`:

```
Expense <- data$Expense 
shapiro.test(Expense)
```

You can loop through the columns (see the `apply` function family), or if you only have a few just repeat the above where relevant.

Depending on what you're trying to figure out there are multiple tests:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test#Frequentist_tests

If you have say a million `Cust_Id` where there are 340 unique, you can create sub-tables for each unique group and test the normality of each group. If this is what you would like I can write a loop that will then give you the normality for specific columns for each of the 340 unique IDs?

Something like:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(data)
```

For one id:

```
id_10 <- data[Cust_Id == 10]
```

Test Expenses of id_10:

```
shapiro.test(id_10$Expense)
```

To loop them:

```
for(i in unique(data$Cust_Id)){
       u <- setDT(data)[Cust_Id == i]
       s <- shapiro.test(u$Expense)
       print(i)
       print(s)
      }
```

Or to create subsets and then apply tests to each:

```
for(i in unique(data$Cust_Id)){
     assign(paste0("id",i),setDT(data)[Cust_Id== i])
    }
```

Another way would be to split by the unique id:

```
 z<-split(data,data$Cust_Id)
for(i in z){print(shapiro.test(i$Expense))}
```

EDIT

To get the results in a table:

Using a sample table:

```
   x <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),y=c(100,10,20,20,35,50,1,2,3,4,5,100),z=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))

df <- setDT(x)[, .(Normality_y = shapiro.test(y), Normality_z = shapiro.test(z), Count = .N), by = a]
```

df will show the normality of y and z columns and the count of unique IDs at the end. Note for each ID the first number in the data frame for normality_y is the W value and the second in the p-value.

To clean this up:

```
library(plyr)
df2 <- ddply(df, "a", function(z) head(z,2))
```

Now for each ID you will have two rows for the W and p value. I've used columns y and z which you can change to expense and income and more. The syntax should be straight forward for adding more columns

Comment: R is not taking the $ value. I tried using your code, but it is not working. Error is "unexpected '$' ". I removed the $ and used  data["Cust_Id"], then again got the error "When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted)". I sorted the data frame, but then again the same error.

Comment: I copied your sample data into excel. Split it into further columns with a space delimiter. Then copied that and got it into R by doing: x <- read.table("clipboard", sep="\t", header=T).  If it is a file you can use read.csv. Is your data a data.table? Have you checked using class(data) where data is the name of the data set?

Comment: Don't use `Expense($)` as the name of the column. It is clear in the example that OP was helping us to know what type of data it held. In their example dataframe you can see the column headers, including `Expense`.

Comment: Ill edit my answer to reflect the example data youve added

Comment: yes @Oli, I have checked. My data set is a data table. I used your modified code still I am not getting any result.

Comment: what does it say when you use split and then loop through z?

Comment: The split function works and I can see the values of z but when I use the loop, I get the error "sample size must be between 3 and 5000". My actual file is huge but for this case I have used a sample csv consisting of only 300 records.

Comment: Okay dont worry, all that is saying is that to use that normality test you need at least 3 numbers. So as long as each unique Cust_Id has at least 3 Cust_Id's you're okay

Comment: ok.. But now where can i see the results of the test. I wanted something like "Cust_ID   Income Normality_Score" and a similar table for Expense.

Comment: Added. using data.table and plyr packages

Comment: @OliPaul What you did at the end (using data.table and plyr) will not work because it will result in the normality of the whole column y and z.

Comment: Yes, but it gives a different score for each unique customer ID which is what you wanted I thought?